# removing duplicate rows based on another column's row

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, data-cleaning, m

I have a table in power bi where table looks like below. What I want to do is that, I want to remove the rows based on type columns. Let's say if one code is repeated and has two different types, I want to remove it based on specified type. For example, if a code is duplicate, then keep the row with Shared type and remove the row where its type is Dedicated. How can I do it in DAX or M Query?

| code | type |
| --- | --- |
| 5055 | Shared |
| 5055 | Dedicated |
| 5056 | Shared |
| 5056 | Dedicated |
| 5057 | Shared |
| 5058 | Dedicated |
| 5059 | Shared |

Comment: I don't know how to write in DAX or MQuery, but you should be able to do a group by on the code and then take the MAX on type (since those are strings it should pick the one that is alphanumerically higher)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a "partition" per code, apply a sort and filter to each partition to return the value required, then combine the partitions:

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WMjUwNVXSUQrOSCxKTVGK1YGLuKSmZCYnliAEzTCUmWFTZo6hzAKbMkskZbEA", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [code = _t, #"type" = _t]),
    #"Partition by code" = Table.Group(Source, {"code"}, {{"Data", each Table.FirstN(Table.Sort(_,{"type", Order.Descending}),1), type table}}),
    #"Combine Partitions" = Table.Combine(#"Partition by code"[Data])
in
    #"Combine Partitions"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this in DAX:

```
ADDCOLUMNS (
    SUMMARIZE(YourTable,[code]),
    "type",CALCULATE(SELECTEDVALUE (YourTable[type],"Shared")))
```

If we test it, It returns:

[image: GGH]